# Unlock Gnome shell takes a long time

Tags: gnome-shell, screen-lock

I lock my GNOME Shell 3.6.3.1 by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as usual but when I try to unlock it takes up to a minute before I get my desktop back.

While waiting I get a black background and a mouse pointer.

Any ideas what takes so long?

Comment: I am also using the same shell version (Ubuntu-13.04) but do not have such issue. Have you modified any key-combination by chance ?

Comment: I use the default shortcuts. Don't think the problem lies with the shortcut. Somethings wrong while unlocking.

Comment: See for traces in `syslog` or `dmesg`

Comment: @SHW nothing odd in syslog and dmesg since boot

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause is, but I remember having similar problems, too. The good news whatever bug was slowing down Gnome 3.6 was fixed in 3.8. Take a look at this question, which addresses something similar: http://askubuntu.com/q/159428/13755

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and didn't know how to debug. But I deactivated all gnome shell extensions and then it worked perfectly.

You can deactivate one by one to find out which extension creates the problem—or you deactivate all and activate one by one again ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Gnome 3.14.0 running under Debian Jessie. The previous answer sent me in the right direction and I discovered that the issue was down to the [Pidgin IM integraton plugin by muffinmad](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/782/pidgin-im-integration/). After disabling this plugin the unlock timeout reverted to normal behaviour.